# Would you prefer a voltmeter or a scope when measuring average voltage precisely?

Tags: oscilloscope, voltmeter

As far as I understood the DC setting of a voltmeter or a multimeter is measuring the average value of a periodic voltage signal(not rms but the average value).

On the other hand, an oscilloscope as well in DC coupling mode also measures the average value of the signal.

Which one in general measures more precise? Why?

Comment: A DVM that is calibrated.

Comment: Non-RMS average is a measurement of questionable value..

Comment: @Andyaka Can there be a situation where the averaging period of voltmeter is much less than the period of the signal? Can an oscilloscope averaging time be adjusted unlike in a DVM case

Comment: How exactly are you going to "Average" a trace on a scope? With your eyeball? By measuring every single plotted point and then taking the average?  Use a DVM.

Comment: @RDrast modern scopes can take average

Comment: @RDrast Every digital oscilloscope I've used since mid eighties has had a 'measure' function that can calculate the average from the waveform.

Comment: Depends entirely on the wanted accuracy and the probe that I currently have in my hand. When I am fiddling with the scope, why bother getting out the meter? When fiddling with the meter, why bother getting out the scope?

Comment: Even given that, a scope is designed to show a waveform. They are typically not terribly accurate for measuring a voltage.  The probe impedance also affects what the scope actually see's. Use a DVM.

Comment: @RDrast The test leads are certainly not better from an impedance point of view than a scope probe. An oscilloscope might only have 8 bits of resolution, but averaging and dithering (caused by noise) will effectively give you a lot of resolution trough supersampling.

Comment: What if you have signal with 50 seconds period? What is the averaging time for a DVM?

Comment: Then you use a digital scope, or a multimeter with a logging function. Any ordinary multimeter will not work in that case.

Comment: Whats the averaging time for an ordinary DVM?

Comment: Also note that if you are going to measure something with a scope, some scopes (Tek, maybe others) have a high-resolution acquisition mode that will oversample and give you better vertical resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scopes are designed to plot waveforms so you can see what the wave-shape looks like. While modern scopes have the ability to do a lot of other things with the data gathered from the ADCs they are not designed as precision measurement devices.

The downside of a basic multimeter is you typically don't have control over the averaging length. If the averaging length is too short compared to the waveform you are measuring then your result won't be an accurate represention of the long term average (and your display will jump around). If it's too long then the reading on your meter will take an annoyingly long time to settle. The more accuracy you need the longer the averaging period you need.

Looking at [Why do DMMs have so low update/refresh rates?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116970/why-do-dmms-have-so-low-update-refresh-rates) it seems that ordinary multimeters make about 4 readings per second. High end bench meters often have settings available to adjust the averaging behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean 4 reading per sec?? Sampling rate???

Comment: sampling rate????

Comment: I mean four readings (i.e. values shown on the display). Depending on the internal design of the meter there may be either analog averaging followed by a single readout or (more likely in a modern meter) many samples taken and averaged digitally to produce a readout.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what's important to you about the signal. There are two issues, accuracy, bandwidth and waveform shape. There are three issues, accuracy, bandwidth, waveform shape and whether you have access to a suitable instrument. There are four [issues ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mog7Gsu613E)

If you want <1% accuracy, you need a suitable meter. If you can tolerate >1% error, a 'scope may do.

However, a meter averages over a certain period, which may or may not be specified in its documentation. You may assume it will always handle mains frequency ripple, but is unlikely to go slower than 1 second (users like quick response) and faster than audio (unless it's a specialist meter). The meter on your bench may or may not be suitable.

A cheap meter will always give you average, which may be OK for your applciation (average current through an electrochemical cell for instance), or no great accuracy required. A more expensive meter may well have true RMS reading (if it has, it will say so), which is better for the heating effect of a current for instance.

While a scope will not have the accuracy of a meter, a modern digital scope will generally allow you to specify a time gate, and do measurements within that. That will allow you to cope with very low frequencies and still make averaged measurements. Generally they have the bandwidth for audio measurements and then some. The nice thing about a digital scope is that you can often dump measurements to a PC. Once there, you can make whatever analysis you want of the signal, within its limited accuracy.

Comment: Actually, there are three issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would trust a DMM more than a scope for accurate DC measurements.

The other answers here already have good technical information, so here's a practical demonstration using VirtualBench:

### DC Measurements: DSO vs DMM [(YouTube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iRukwIy_Dg)

The test signal is a 100 kHz square wave with a small DC offset from the function generator. The signal is being measured by both the oscilloscope and the DMM. The scope measures both the signal's mean and RMS (as defined by IEEE 181-2011), and the mean is within 2-5% of the DMM's measurement, hinting at how the DMM measures DC Volts on periodic signals.

Changing the duty cycle of the square wave changes the mean, and both the scope and DMM reflect that, but the scope still has some error in the single-digit percents. Even enabling averaging on the scope doesn't improve its accuracy much.

Comment: Unfortunately not such a clear cut answer. The accuracy of your instruments will also vary.

Comment: Phew! It's a good thing those other answers are there.